# How to plot a horizontal dotted line over other plots, with a label over it, and points with labels over them (MATLAB)?

Tags: matlab

I need to plot a horizontal dotted line in a graph with other plots, I need to put a label over it, and I need to add points to the graph with labels over them. How do I do this in Matlab?

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation for `line` or `plot`? With `plot` you would need to do `hold on` to overlay multiple lines. Have you looked at the documentation for `text` to add labels? Please add a [mcve] for your plot to highlight the specific bit of this process you're stuck on

Answer (score -1):

Matlab has a yline function which plots a horizontal line with a label added to it. If you have several plots, like a subplot, then you have to apply that function on every subplot.

https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/yline.html